# How do I replace subscrib in a subscribe in Angular RxJS?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscribe, switchmap

I have a question about RxJS.
I am creating a web app to manage the members of an association.
I want to create a button to "reset" the database of a site.
The steps are as follows:

- send an e-mail to all members to re-register
- Delete data
- Refresh page

Here's the code I've made, which works, but I know there are a few things wrong. I'm new to RxJS, so I don't quite understand all the principles...

```
newYear(){
    this.amicalisteService.getAmicalistesValides("").subscribe({
      // Envoyer un mail à l'ensemble des amicalistes valides
      next: amicalistes => {
        for(const amicaliste of amicalistes) {
          const to = amicaliste.email;
          const cc = null;
          const subject = "Adhère à l'AEIR";
          const body = ""
          this.amicalisteService.sendMail(null, to, cc, subject, body).subscribe({
            next: response => {
              console.log('E-mail envoyé avec succès !', response);
            },
            error: error => {
              console.error('Erreur lors de l\'envoi de l\'e-mail :', error);
            }
          });
        }
      },
      complete: () => {
        // Supprimer amicalistes, photos et cartes amicalistes
        this.amicalisteService.getAmicalistes().subscribe(amicalistes  => {
          for(const amicaliste of amicalistes){
            this.amicalisteService.deleteAmicalisteById(amicaliste.id).subscribe();
          }
        });
        this.imageService.getImages("amicaliste").subscribe(images => {
          for(const image of images){
            this.imageService.deleteImageByName("amicaliste", this.imageService.getImageName(image.toString())).subscribe();
          }
        });
        this.imageService.getImages("pdf").subscribe(pdfs => {
          for(const pdf of pdfs){
            this.imageService.deleteImageByName("pdf", this.imageService.getImageName(pdf.toString())).subscribe();
          }
        })
      }
      //Refresh...
    })
  }
```

I've heard it's not good practice to use subscribe() inside subscribe(), but I can't figure out how to do it differently.
There are several things I'd like to keep in this code, however. In the complete, the 3 subscribe() run in parallel, if I'm not mistaken. I'd like to keep that.
Otherwise, I understand that using a switchMap could help me, but I can't seem to implement it. Can anyone give me some advice?

Thanks you very much !

Comment: Your current approach feels very imperative. RX is usually more about declarative data flows and mixing combinators

Comment: How can I solve this problem using a more declarative approach ?

Comment: By using operators (such as `concatMap`, `forkJoin`, etc...) and pipeable observables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I basically turn a lot of your observables into one, relying mostly on `flatMap` (`concatMap` when it comes to rxjs) and `forkJoin` to combine multiple observables into one which is analogous to `Promise.all` for promises.

There's no "monadic" flat map (that I could find) sadly, so we have to map arrays of values to arrays of observable and `forkJoin` them.

```
this.amicalisteService.getAmicalistesValides("").pipe(
  concatMap(amicalistes => { // Observable<Amicaliste[]> -> Observable<void[]>
    return forkJoin( // Observable<void>[] -> Observable<void[]>
      amicalistes.map(amicaliste => { // Amicaliste -> Observable<void>
        const to = amicaliste.email;
          const cc = null;
          const subject = "Adhère à l'AEIR";
          const body = ""
          return this.amicalisteService.sendMail(null, to, cc, subject, body)
            .pipe(tap({
              next: response => {
                console.log('E-mail envoyé avec succès !', response);
              },
              error: error => {
                console.error('Erreur lors de l\'envoi de l\'e-mail :', error);
              }
            }));
      })
    );
  }),

  // Then, when the above is completed, execute the rest
  concatMap(() => forkJoin([
    this.amicalisteService.getAmicalistes()
      .pipe(
        concatMap(amicalistes => {
          return forkJoin(amicalistes.map(amicaliste => this.amicalisteService.deleteAmicalisteById(amicaliste.id)));
        })
      ),
    this.imageService.getImages("amicaliste")
      .pipe(
        concatMap(images => {
          return forkJoin(
            images.map(image => this.imageService.deleteImageByName("amicaliste", this.imageService.getImageName(image.toString())))
          )
        })
      ),
    this.imageService.getImages("pdf")
      .pipe(
        concatMap(pdfs => {
          return forkJoin(
            pdfs.map(pdf => this.imageService.deleteImageByName("pdf", this.imageService.getImageName(pdf.toString())))
          )
        })
      )
  ])), 
);
```

Comment: Maybe the monadic behavior you are looking for is provided by `mergeMap` which, by the way, could be used instead of `forkJoin` to control the number of concurrent “live” streams (i.e. the number of concurrent calls to remote services).

Comment: Sadly `mergeMap` doesn't really cut it. What I wanted was a `Observable<T[]> -> (T -> Observable<U>) -> Observable<U[]>`, but `mergeMap` looks like a `Observable<T> -> (T -> U[]) -> Observable<U>`

Answer (score 2):

Observables are streams of events.

Remote calls (e.g. calling a server to send mails or calling a db to clean up some data) are implemented as streams of events that notify just one event (i.e. the response of the remote call) and then `complete` or just `error○s.

With RxJs operators you can combine such streams. For instance you do the following:

- you start with one stream, **Stream_A**, that emits **event_A** and then completes
- you can have a second stream, **Stream_B**, that emits **event_B** and then completes
- and then you combine **Stream_A** and **Stream_B** to create a third stream, **Stream_A_B** that first *triggers* the execution of **Stream_A** and emits **event_A** and, as soon as **event_A** has been notified, *triggers* the execution of **Stream_B** and emits all the events notified by **Stream_B**, which in this case is just **event_B**
- In order to create this combined stream in RxJs we use the oprator `concatMap` (note: often people use `switchMap` to concatenate streams - often the result is the same but the meaning and the potential behaviors are slightly different - with sequences of calls to remote services which have to occur one after the other, `concatMap` is usually the preferred approach)

Another example of combination of more streams to obtain a new stream is the following:

- There are 2 streams, **Stream_1** **Stream_2** and **Stream_3**. Each of these streams emits one value and then completes.
- We can combine these 3 streams that waits for all 3 streams to emit and complete and then emits only one value, which is the array of all values emitted by the streams, and then complete.
- With RxJs such new combined stream is obtained with the function `forkJoin`

Havin said that, with the hope to cast some clarity on RxJs and Observables, here is what I would do in your case

```
newYear(){
    // assume getAmicalistesValides returns an Observable that emits the result
    // of a remote call
    this.amicalisteService.getAmicalistesValides("")
    // to combine Observables we need to "pipe" operators, i.e. to execute
    // operators one after the other
    .pipe(
      // first thing to do here seems to send an email for each amicaliste
      // assuming we want to send the emails all in parallel, we can first
      // create one Observable for each mail to be sent and then use forkJoin
      // to execute them all in parallel
      // But all this has to happen after the Observable returned by getAmicalistesValides
      // has emitted its value, hence we use concatMap
      concatMap(amicalistes => {
        for(const amicaliste of amicalistes) {
          const to = amicaliste.email;
          const cc = null;
          const subject = "Adhère à l'AEIR";
          const body = ""
          // here we create the array of Observables
          const sendMailObs = this.amicalisteService.sendMail(null, to, cc, subject, body)
          // each of these Observables can print something or react to errors
          .pipe(tap({
            next: response => {
              console.log('E-mail envoyé avec succès !', response);
            },
            error: error => {
              console.error('Erreur lors de l\'envoi de l\'e-mail :', error);
            }))
          });
          // now we trigger the concurrent execution of all sendMail observables
          return forkJoin(sendMailObs)
      }),
      // after having sent the mails you want to do more stuff: delete data, images
      // and so on - assume each of these operations is an Observable
      // you will have to use concatMap and within it create the new Observables
      // and trigger them in parallel using forkJoin, as above
      concatMap(mailSentResults => {
         const deleteDataObs = ....
         const deleteImagesObs = ...
         ...
         return forkJoin([deleteDataObs, deleteImagesObs, // maybe other Obsevables])
      })
    )
    // up to here you have created a new stream, composing various other streams
    // and now is the time to subscribe to this new stream, which is the only stream 
    // you want to explicitely subscribe
    .subscribe({
      next: res => ... // manage the value notified by upstream
      error: err => ... // manage error
      complete: () => ... // do something when all is completed, if required
    })
  }
```

I hope I have understood your case and all this makes some sense

Comment: This is really clear, thanks for this explaination !

Comment: As a sidenote, the main difference between `concatMap` and `switchMap` is that `concatMap` is complete and exhaustive, where `switchMap` would "switch" to the latest value/snapshot as soon as possible.